# Repository Pattern Books

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern

I would like to know a good introducing book for Repository Pattern using Entity Framework.
Do you know any? thanks

Comment: It's not a book, but read this. http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern/. And it maybe a bit hard for a beginner to understand.

Comment: thanks for your suggested article, I also I found a good one for begiiners http://tdryan.blogspot.com/2011/03/another-entity-framework-4-repository_816.html .. off course would be great know a book but I cannot found any.

Comment: also this http://weblogs.asp.net/thangchung/archive/2010/07/20/the-short-example-about-entity-framework-4-ctp4-part-2.aspx and http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/using-repository-pattern

Comment: See also: http://deviq.com/repository-pattern/ which describes the pattern and use with EF

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the book about [Entity Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596807260), relevant parts from the book about [enterprise application patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420) and the book about [domain driven design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321268202). You must first understand every single part to use it correctly.

Once you understand topics answer few questions:

- Why do you need repository?
- What will repository solve for you?
- Why is EF itself not sufficient for that?
- Will it help if you wrap EF to repository?
- etc.

Until you don't know at least expected answers for these questions you don't need to bother with repository pattern. The main rule of pattern usage: A pattern should be used when it is needed not because it exists. The boom of all these repository articles goes against this rule and moreover most of these articles are wrong using either wrong code (like passing `Func<>` to queries instead of `Expression<Func<>>`) or bad assumptions (like saying that using repository will make your code unit testable).

Comment: Thanks for your links and comment on this. I appreciate.